# C# Check If Text File Has Content

Tags: c#, wpf, button, if-statement

I am building a C# WPF Browser App (my C# skills are quite rusty).

I have a button that I want to have change color depending on if a text document has anything in it. IE: Color is Green if there is any text in it, or Red if it is empty.

Can someone please push me off in the right direction.
Thank you.

Comment: When you say a text document, do you mean one on disk? Or something they will be currently editing in a text area or something?

Comment: It will be a file on the HDD that stays the in the same location, but the contents will differ.

Comment: @Woo, see the link in my answer below. A bit length, but should give you a lot of little nuggets to chew on during your WPF development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at System.IO.FileInfo

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo( "<file path>" );
if( f.Length > 0 ) 
  // Color button green
else 
  // Color button red
```

Note that if you keep f around and plan to check it again later, you will have to call f.Refresh() to ensure it has the latest information.

Comment: Sorry to be a complete n00b, could you provide an example of this? Where to put the code in the Page1.xaml.cs?

Comment: Well, do you want to do it once at startup?  Then I'd put it in the window's load event.  If you want to periodically check it, I would use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly I am very late on this one, but my answer turned into a big blog post.

[Here is a full solution using FileSystemWatcher and all the WPF bells and whistles](http://www.technofattie.com/2011/02/11/wpf-fancy-winforms.html)

Hopefully you get some use out of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.Color = (new FileInfo("foo.bar")).Length == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
```